# Is there a way to add relationships in a custom profile?

Tags: contacts, custom-fields, profile, relationships, forms

I am creating profiles so that people in the organisation can input contacts easily. I can create a form that has all the individuals information that I need (name etc.) but I am struggling to work out how I can add relationships to other contacts (individuals and organisations) from this form.

Is this something that is possible?

When I try to create a field that links to an organisation it comes up with an error button and says it is invalid because the profile is for an individual. It won't let me create a form for multiple types of contacts.

On Word press and civie 5.39.0.

Comment: Can you add which CMS are you using and Civi version?

Answer (score 1):

So I just went through and created a custom profile. I added three fields drawn from individual:
First Name
Last Name
Current Employer

I entered a sample with a local business and the resulting contact had the appropriate relationship.

Is this what you were trying to accomplish?

Comment: It is thank you! I'm not quite sure what you mean by sample? Could you explain - thank you!

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that I went to my own CiviCRM and I created a profile (as a sample for your issue) and I added three fields. When you add a field, it asks what form to draw the field from. In all three, I selected individual as the form and I chose first name, last name and Current Employer.
Employer created the relationship as expected.

Comment: I see - yes that's worked for me. My issue is how to create a relationship that isn't on the form. For example if I want to say an MP is a member of X party do you know of a way of doing that?

Comment: Speculation here, but I'll give you something to try.
The fields are drawn from existing forms, so add a custom field to contact doing what you want "party membership" 
That field should be an option after that when you go to your custom profile creation/edit.

Comment: "Current employer" is unusual in that it is available as a field for a profile. this isn't an option for other relationships. folk usually would do this in WP via Caldera Forms I think. Other options "an auto-reference field you can use that to create a link between a participant and another contact", or CiviRules (ref: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11600/creating-a-relationship-when-filling-in-a-profile)